# Weighted least-squares when weights are not known

Tags: residuals, weighted-regression

I have two questions while I am doing a weighted non-linear least-squares fit.

1. I vaguely remember from some class that the weights should be 1/abs(residuals), or 1/(residuals^2). I am not sure what I should be using. What's the criteria?
2. When using the weights w, should the cost function calculate 'residuals x w', or 'residuals x sqrt(w)'

Answer (score 0):

In a least-squares fit, it is the numerator that equals $(data-model)^2= (residual)^2$ in the quantity $\Delta^2$ you are building.

The weights depend on what you want to do.  Generally (for reasons of goodness-of-fit estimation and interval estimation), one wants a $\Delta^2$ that follows a $\chi^2$ distribution, so you build the $\Delta^2$ as the sum of the squares of several standard normal variables.  A standard normal variable can be obtained from a normal variable by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.